# I need to get GLDAS S.M data for a certain location but i get "User memory limit exceeded". any solution?

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series

Here is the link to the code on GEE: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ade50fa01b049d4ccf86a4c7f3f6c2dc

```
Map.addLayer(table ,{},'DAM_irri',true);
//var geometry_one = geometry;
var geometry_one = table;

//imagae of GLDAS
var allGLDAS =ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H")
.filterDate('2020-7-01','2021-01-01')
.filterBounds ( geometry_one )
.select('SoilMoi0_10cm_inst')
.median();

//DRAW GLDAS 
var GLDAS2020=ee.ImageCollection(allGLDAS)
.filterDate('2020-7-01','2021-01-01')
.select('SoilMoi0_10cm_inst');

var GLDASvis = {
  min: 250.0,
 max: 300.0,
 palette: ['1303ff', '42fff6', 'f3ff40', 'ff5d0f'],
};

Map.addLayer(allGLDAS.clip(geometry_one),GLDASvis,"GLDAS2020");
Map.centerObject(geometry_one,2)

print(ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(allGLDAS, geometry_one, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'SoilMoi0_10cm_inst', 100));
```

Comment: Share your table

Comment: Thank you  that is ok